# Detectar colisión de imagenes en python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Sé que para éstas cosas es mejor *pygame*, pero quiero probar en *tkinter* solo para ver.

la cosa es que quiero mover una esfera y que atraviese un laberinto, algo simple, pero quiero ver que cuando llegue a los muros no las pase
Hice unos botoncitos para que la imagen se mueva a medida que vaya apretando, y luego iré agregando más cosas, sólo quería saber si sigo con esto o mejor me paso a *pygame* o *turtle* o como se llamen las demás librerías.

Por ahora he puesto que los muros aparezcan encima de la bola, pero no sé como hacer para que no se toquen.

Hasta los puse en diferentes `labeles` para que sea más fácil.

```
import tkinter as tk

def arriba():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global ima
    
    posx = posx
    posy -= 4 
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=myimg)
    canvas.delete(image2)
    canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image2)

def abajo():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global ima
    
    posx = posx
    posy += 4
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=myimg)
    canvas.delete(image2)
    canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image2)

def derecha():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global ima
    
    posx -= 4
    posy = posy
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=myimg)
    canvas.delete(image2)
    canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image2)

def izquierda():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global ima
    
    posx += 4
    posy = posy
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=myimg)
    canvas.delete(image2)
    canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image2)


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)


frame = tk.Frame(ventana)
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=900, height=800)
canvas.pack()

image=tk.PhotoImage(file="labetinto.gif")
canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image)


myimg = tk.PhotoImage(file='circlo.png')
posx=70
posy=235
ima = canvas.create_image(70,235,image=myimg)

frame2 = tk.Frame(ventana)
frame.pack()
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(frame2, width=900, height=800)
canvas.pack()

image2=tk.PhotoImage(file="muros.png")
canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image2)


boton = tk.Button(text="  ↑  ",font=("Verdana",17),command=arriba)
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=750,y=330)

boton1 = tk.Button(text="  ↓  ",font=("Verdana",17),command=abajo)
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=750,y=423)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16))
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=751,y=379)

boton3 = tk.Button(text=" → " ,font=("Verdana",17),command=izquierda)
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=817,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(text=" ← ",font=("Verdana",17),command=derecha)
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=690,y=376)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: una colisión es cuando 2 objetos están en la misma posición, esa es la lógica.

Comment: pero entonces no se puede hacer?

Comment: nunca dije eso, creo que puedes programar cualquier cosa, si sabes la lógica solo busca la forma en que se puede hacer

Comment: ah oka, gracias :)

Comment: Yo en lo personal, si sabes lo suficiente sobre clases derivadas, recomiendo que utilises el modulo [Arcade](https://arcade.academy/).

Comment: Tkinter tiene el objetivo de ser una gui, no tiene ningún comando para detectar colisiones. Podrías usar rects de pygame para detectarlas. Si quieres doy una respuesta explicando como lo podrías hacer, te parece bien?

Comment: @Christian dos objetos no necesariamente tienen que estar en la misma posición para colisionar. Con que sus mascaras de colisión se toquen es suficiente para que sea una colisión.

Comment: Otra cosa, te recomiendo agregar las etiquetas Python y Tkinter a tu pregunta.

Comment: Seria genial amigo :)

Comment: Algo que no tiene que ver con tu duda pero que de verdad que te va a facilitar un montón la vida... te recomiendo que aprendas a programar orientado a objetos! Te evitas poner 4 veces ( y lo acabarás poniendo aun más veces) cada variable *global*